# Android: Get highest value in column

Tags: sql, database, android, aggregate

I have an URL pointing to content and I need to get the highest value contained in one of the columns. Is there any aggregate function that will accomplish that or do I have to do this manually?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're querying an Android content provider, you should be able to achieve this by passing `MAX(COLUMN_NAME)` in to the selection parameter of `ContentResolver.query`:

```
getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, "MAX(COLUMN_NAME)", null, sortOrder);
```

Where Uri is the address of the content provider. This should return the single row with the highest value in COLUMN_NAME.

Comment: `"MAX(COLUMN_NAME)"` should be used as the projection, not the selection.

Comment: why we have to set sortOrder?

Answer (score 1):

Android's database uses SQLite, so `SELECT MAX(thecolumn) FROM TheTable` should work, just like in any other SQLite implementation (or for that matter any other SQL, "ite" or not;-). (If you're not using `android.database` you'd better specify *what* you're using instead;-).

Comment: I'm using ContentResolver.query(...). Is it possible there? What field to use?

Answer (score 1):

That worked for me.

Based on the responses of @Reto Meier and @Florian von Stosch.

```
public static long getMaxId(Context context) {

    long maxId = 0;

    Cursor maxCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            ProviderContentContract.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{"MAX(" + Table._ID + ")"},
            null,
            null,
            null);

    if (maxCursor != null && maxCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        maxId = maxCursor.getInt(0);
         maxCursor.close();
    }
    return maxId;
}
```