# How to fetch the maximum call duration record from Contacts database in android, using a cursor?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I was using the below code to retrieve the maximum call duration from the call logs database in android after following the thread: [Querying the max value of a column in SQLite For Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693439/querying-the-max-value-of-a-column-in-sqlite-for-android).

```
Cursor cur = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,new String[]{ "MAX("+CallLog.Calls.DURATION+")"}, null,null, null);
```

and I got this runtime error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column MAX(duration)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Change your query statement to

`Cursor cur = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null,"MAX("+CallLog.Calls.DURATION+")",null, null);`

The arguments passed into `managedQuery()` are `(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)`.
You are passing `MAX(duration)` in place of second argument i.e. `String[] projection` which is basically to decide "from which columns you want data".
Since there is no column named `MAX(duration)` hence the error.

What you want is to pass it in 3rd argument i.e. `String selection` to "select" max of a column.

Edit: 
managedQuery() is deprecated and the following link answers the question perfectly. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5006853/6168097

Comment: Thats not the case since, in the sql statement being formed ,it is getting placed in the WHERE clause instead of SELECT MAX(duration), following your method.

Comment: I dug a little more and found that `managedQuery()` is deprecated and found exact solution to your problem.

Comment: This should do it.